# SPMetal: How to override it to use internal name instead of “Display Name”

Tags: linq, sharepoint-2010, linq-to-sharepoint

So I am using SPmetal tool to generate data classes to use LINQ to SharePoint.

A feature of the tool is aliasing the site column by its Display name.

How can I override SPMetal setting to use Internal name or static name?

Comment: i think is not possible by design

Comment: You may be able to do it manually by using a parameters xml file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535056(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Consider to use other strongly-typed framework, such as http://sharepointcommon.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameters.xml for overridde column name.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535056(v=office.14).aspx